# Fontawesome newcommand is generating an error

Tags: fontspec, fontawesome

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newfontfamily\fontawesome[]{fonts/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf}
\setfontfamily\fontawesome[]{fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf}

\newcommand\fasymbol[1]{{\fontawesome\symbol{"F#1}}}
\newcommand\faAbout{\textcolor{black}{\fasymbol{2C0}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{\faAbout Contact}
   
\end{document}
```

The MWE above generates no output but a ton of errors. If one substitutes the line `\section*{\faAbout Contact}` for simply `\section*{Contact}`, the MWE above generates a document. Therefore, there must be something wrong with the way I’m calling `fontawesome`, but I do not know what it is.

I have created a folder called `fonts` and within it, another folder named `fontawesome`. In this folder, I have placed the `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` and the `FontAwesome.otf` files. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you defining `\fontawesome` twice with different font files? Why aren't you using the LaTeX packages for fontawesome? Where are you getting the font files from?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I don’t remember where I got the fonts from. I am nonetheless defining a class that needs to be compiled using `xelatex`, and using `\RequirePackage{fontawesome}` and the commands provided by this package generates an error of the type `missing number, treated as zero`… This error can be reproduced with the MWE I provided, although it’s not a fatal error and the desired output is still generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit paths work best in fontspec when they are passed with the option `Path`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newfontfamily\fontawesome[Path=fonts/fontawesome/,Extension=.otf]{FontAwesome}

\newcommand\fasymbol[1]{{\fontawesome\symbol{"F#1}}}
\newcommand\faAbout{\textcolor{black}{\fasymbol{2C0}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{\faAbout Contact}
   
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can just use the fontawesome5 package:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\section*{\faUser[regular] Contact}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error if I use the `fontawesome5` package rather than the `fontawesome` one.

Comment: "tons of errors" is not a sensible problem description. Tell the exact wording of the first error of Marcel's fontawesome5-example.  You should also tell exactly which tex system you use. Put e.g. the full log-file somewhere.